# Is any way to fix NewConnectionError occurred while calling a API?

Tags: node.js, api, request

I am trying to call an API which used to work fine previously, suddenly it started to throw newConnectionError. How can I get this fixed?

I tried to run the same API on my local machine and on the test environment, working fine there.

I expect a successful connection.

Error Message:

eport (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establ
ish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)).

Comment: What frameworks/libraries are you using to connect to the api? Also show your code  parts in which the error is thrown.

Comment: Does it only happen in certain networks? Could be a proxy issue. 110 normally is a timeout, right?

Comment: It seems your server has been down for a while.